# Approximation for $(1 - \frac{1}{x})^x$

Tags: asymptotics, approximation

According to this [survey paper](https://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/postscripts/im2005b.pdf) on Bloom Filters, we can do the following approximation

$$(1 - \frac{1}{m})^{kn} \approx e^{\frac{-kn}{m}}$$

which allegedly is a $O(\frac 1m)$ approximation. I am curious as to why this is so. I know that:

- $(1 - \frac{1}{x})^x$ eventually converges to $e^{-1}$ because of L'Hospital's rule.
- $(1 - \frac{1}{x})^x$ can be expressed as $e^{-1} \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-1}{(i+1)x^i}} $ using a Taylor expansion.

However, I don't see a clean way of showing that it is a $O(\frac 1m)$ approximation.

Answer (score 18):

We have:
$$
\left(1 - \frac{1}{x}\right)^x = e^{x\log\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)} = e^{x\left(-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)} = e^{\left(-{1}-\frac{1}{2x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)}$$

by Taylor expansion of $\log(1-t)$ at $0$.
Then by expanding the exponential :
$$
 e^{\left(-\frac{1}{2x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)} =
1-\frac{1}{2x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) + o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = 1+O(1/x)
$$

So that plugging everything back:
$$\left(1 - \frac{1}{x}\right)^x = e^{-1}(1+O(1/x)) = e^{-1}+O(1/x)$$

Comment: Ahh I should have discarded the higher order terms for an asymptotic. Thank you!

Comment: @iart I am not sure what you did, but the asymptotic should be exactly the same even if you keep higher-order terms. That is always the case with O-notation arithmetic.

Comment: If you have more terms in the bigO you can collapse them, for instance, $O(1/x^2)+O(1/x^3)$ is a $O(1/x^2)$. Doing the computations with an arbitrary long Taylor expansion should yield the same result in the end. If you're happy with this answer, please mark it as Solved!

Comment: Oh, wow, changing sign inside the brackets changes sign in power of $e$.

Comment: Yup marked it as solved.